# Calculus 2 -Calculate the integral $\int_1^2 f(x) dx$ if $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$, $\int_0^2 f(x) dx$ and $\int_1^4$ are given

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate  $\int_1^2 f(x) dx $

Assuming

$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx = -89$
$\int_0^2 f(x) dx = 87 $
$\int_1^4 = -21 $

Things I've tried

1) $\int_1^2 f(x) dx =  \int_1^4 f(x)dx- \int_0^1 f(x) dx -  
\int_0^2 f(x) dx ,     
 $

Which would become

$-21 + 89 -87= -19$

which was not the answer webwork said.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.   Shouldn't the answer be just $\int_0^2 f(x) dx - \int_0^1 f(x) dx = 87 - (-89) = 176$ ?

Comment: @Shailesh -- That's correct, But why leave the -21 out?

Comment: Remember .. Integral is area under the curve... so area from 1 to 2 is area from 0 to 2 minus area from 0 to 1

Comment: Got it, Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

For $f$ integrable on $[0,4]$ we have
$$\int_1^2f(x)dx=\int_0^2f(x)dx-\int_0^1f(x)dx$$